# unable to setText in Java Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hey I am creating a java project. In which I have a insert record frame, on insert frame I have a option to enter father ID and if the user did not know the father id, so I have set a button to find the father id.
when the user will click on that button, the new frame will appear and user can search for id, the result will show in a table and when user click on the particular record, the frame will dispose and should set the respective id on the previous frame.

I have written the code for it, and it is passing the value to the previous frame but it is not setting the value to the textfield that I want it to be. Where I am doing wrong? Here is the code.

FamilyInsert.java

```
public class FamilyInsert extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form FamilyInsert
 */

int id = DBManager.genID();
public int fid;
public FamilyInsert() {
    initComponents();
    txtId.setText(""+id);
    txtName.requestFocus();
}



public void setFid(int fid){
    txtFid.setText(""+fid);
    System.out.println("setFID "+fid);
}

public void reset()
{
    txtName.setText("");
    txtFather.setText("");
    txtFid.setText("");
    txtCity.setText("");
    txtState.setText("");
    txtName.requestFocus();

}


private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   int id = Integer.parseInt(txtId.getText());
   String name = txtName.getText();
   String fname = txtFather.getText();
   int fid = Integer.parseInt(txtFid.getText());
   String city = txtCity.getText();
   String state = txtState.getText();
   Family family = new Family(id,name,fname,fid, city,state);
    boolean flag = false;

    flag = DBManager.insertMember(family);
    if(flag==true){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Successfully Saved");
        id++;
        txtId.setText(""+id);
        reset();
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error Occured");
    }



}                                         

private void txtFidActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  SearchFatherFrame f = new SearchFatherFrame();
  f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  f.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

and from the search frame:

```
 private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
       int id;
        if(evt.getClickCount()==2){
            if(jTable1.getSelectedRow()!=-1)
            {
                int index = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                Family s = list.get(index);
                id = s.getId();
                System.out.println("ID from search frame "+id);
                FamilyInsert f = new FamilyInsert();
                f.setFid(id);
                this.dispose();
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s.getId()+"\n"+s.getName());                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: is `FamilyInsert` the class which holds the GUI??

Comment: Common newbie problem here: This is wrong `new FamilyInsert();`. Don't want to create a *new* FamilyInsert object but rather set the text of the already existing object. You need to understand what objects/instances are and what references are, and then use that knowledge to help you pass the correct reference to where it is needed.

Comment: Yes.. It is the Insert frame, where user has to insert all the record and the search frame is the second frame which should return the value and then dispose.

Comment: Also, no you don't want to use multiple JFrames. Please see: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating a ***new*** FamilyInsert object within the other class, and changing its state, but this leaves the state of the original FamilyInsert object unchanged. What you need to do instead is to pass a reference of the original displayed FamilyInsert into the 2nd object, and then change its state.

Change this:

```
SearchFatherFrame f = new SearchFatherFrame();
```

to something more like:

```
SearchFatherFrame f = new SearchFatherFrame(this);
```

Pass the reference into the class and use to set a field:

```
public class SearchFatherFrame {
    private FamilyInsert familyInsert;

    public SearchFatherFrame(FamilyInsert familyInsert) {
        this.familyInsert = familyInsert;
        // other code....
    }
}
```

Then use that reference passed in to change the state of the original object.

```
if(jTable1.getSelectedRow()!=-1) {
    int index = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    Family s = list.get(index);
    id = s.getId();
    System.out.println("ID from search frame "+id);

    // FamilyInsert f = new FamilyInsert();
    // f.setFid(id);
    familyInsert.setFid(id); // **** add

    this.dispose();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s.getId()+"\n"+s.getName());                    
}
```

Also you want the 2nd window to be a JDialog not a JFrame. Please see: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much.. It works.. Sure, I will definitely avoid using Multiple JFrames.

Comment: @PankajChaudhary: much more important is do you understand the conceptual issue at play here and why your original code did not work? Objects are self-contained entities, and changing the state of one (your new FamilyInsert object) will not magically affect the state of another (the original and displayed FamilyInsert object). This is a key concept that you have to know inside and out to move forward. Please ask if any questions.

Answer (score -2):

Could you try

```
public void setFid(int fid){
        txtFid.setText(""+fid);
        System.out.println("setFID "+fid);
        yourJFrame.setVisible(true); //Reloads the frame
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking about it.. Sry

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not addressing the main problem -- that of changing the state of the wrong reference, and still giving wrong advice.